# Mocking a service with a promise, for testing within another service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, promise

I have the following service (reduced for simplicity):

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('BasicTimerService', function BasicTimerService(PromiseService)
    {
        var isPlaying = false,
            maxEventTime = 0;

        return {
            start: function()
            {
                // only "start" once this promise has resolved.
                PromiseService.get_promise()
                    .then(function(value)
                    {
                        maxEventTime = PromiseService.maxEventTime();
                        isPlaying = true;
                    });
            },
            get_isPlaying: function() {
                return isPlaying;
            }
        };
    });
```

I wish to test that maxEventTime is only set after the Promise is successful.

My test:

```
describe('Service: BasicTimerService', function () {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var mockPromiseService,
        BasicTimerService,
        $q,
        $rootScope,
        deferred;

    beforeEach(function(){
        mockPromiseService = {
            maxEventTime: function() {
                return 17000;
            }
        };

        module(function($provide){
            $provide.value('PromiseService', mockPromiseService);
        });

        inject(function(_BasicTimerService_, _$q_, _$rootScope_){
            BasicTimerService = _BasicTimerService_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $q = _$q_;
        });

        mockPromiseService.get_promise = function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve('hello world');
            return deferred.promise;
        };
    });

    it('should get maxEventTime once the promise is resolved.', function() {
        spyOn(mockPromiseService, 'get_promise').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(mockPromiseService, 'maxEventTime').and.callThrough();

        $rootScope.$apply();

        BasicTimerService.start();

        expect(mockPromiseService.get_promise).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(BasicTimerService.get_isPlaying()).toBe(true);
        expect(mockPromiseService.maxEventTime).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I've determined that mockPromiseService.get_promise() is successfully called (the first expect() is successful), but the .then() clause in BasicTimerService does not seem to be called, and I cannot figure out why.

I have tried using both `$rootScope.$apply();` as well as `$rootScope.$digest();` to no avail.

Any ideas as to why this does not work?

Comment: Return the promise from `start`. As a rule if something performs I/O it should always return a promise for that io's completion (or take a callback in the callbacks version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `start()` method is asynchronous, so if it is working properly, `get_isPlaying()` will not be `true` by the time you check its value. You need to await the result (modify `start()` to return a promise as Benjamin Gruenbaum has suggested:

```
it('should get maxEventTime once the promise is resolved.', function(done) {
    spyOn(mockPromiseService, 'get_promise').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(mockPromiseService, 'maxEventTime').and.callThrough();

    $rootScope.$apply();

    BasicTimerService.start().then(function () {
        expect(mockPromiseService.get_promise).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(BasicTimerService.get_isPlaying()).toBe(true);
        expect(mockPromiseService.maxEventTime).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    });
});
```

You also don't need to use `$q.defer()` in `get_promise` (you should almost never need to use `$q.defer()`):

```
mockPromiseService.get_promise = function() {
    return $q.when('hello world');
};
```

Note: Based on the `$q` documentation, it looks like you can use `$rootScope.$apply()` to get promise values to propagate to their `then` handlers, but I am of the opinion that you should treat promises as promises and use `.then()`, etc. to test them.

Comment: I had to move $rootScope.apply() to the last line of my test, but all else worked as stated. Thanks for your help!